# how to Pass the button ID in a switch statement to do whichever function that button is supposed to do?

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement

This is a simple calculator using HTML and Javascript and I am supposed to use a switch statement to select which mathematical operation to do after pressing the relevant button. I don't know what I should pass inside the switch though.
This is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
p{
color:white;
 background-color:black;
 } 
 </style>
<script>
function simple_calculator(){
 var numl=0;
 var num2=0;
 var result=0;
  num1 = document.getElementById("no1").value;
 num2 = document.getElementById("no2").value;
 num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("no2").value);
  num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("no2").value); 

 switch(op) {
    case 1:
        result = num1 + num2;
        break;
    case 2:             
        result = num1 - num2;
        break;
    case 3:
        result = num1 * num2;
        break;
    case 4:
        result = num1 / num2;
        break;





 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;

 default:
 }

 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h3>*- - - Simple Calculator - --*</h3>
<textarea id = "no1"> </textarea>
<textarea id = "no2"> </textarea>
 <button id="add" onclick="simple_calculator(1);">Add</button>
<button id="sub" onclick="simple_calculator(2);"> Subsract</button>
 <button id="mul" onclick="simple_calculator(3);">Multiply</button>
 <button id="div" onclick="simple_calculator(4);">Divide</button>

<p id="result"></p>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the value from the onclick handler function call into the function simple_calculator function , so try this:

```
function simple_calculator(op) { // op should be an argument

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `simple_calculator` should return a function as you are invoking it immediately on assigning as event handler:

```
function simple_calculator(op){
  return function wrap() {
    var numl=0;
    var num2=0;
    var result=0;
    num1 = document.getElementById("no1").value;
    num2 = document.getElementById("no2").value;
    num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("no2").value);
    num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("no2").value);

    switch(op) {
      case 1:
        result = num1 + num2;
        break;
      case 2:
        result = num1 - num2;
        break;
      case 3:
        result = num1 * num2;
        break;
      case 4:
        result = num1 / num2;
        break;
      default:
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `onclick="simple_calculator(this.id)"`where this is is the id of the element, and you use the id for the switch

```js
function simple_calculator(id) {
 
  var num1 = 0;
  var num2 = 0;
  var result = 0;

  num1 = parseInt(no1.value) || 0;
  num2 = parseInt(no2.value) || 0;
  
 
    switch (id) {
      case "add":
        result = num1 + num2;
        break;
      case "sub":
        result = num1 - num2;
        break;
      case "mul":
        result = num1 * num2;
        break;
      case "div":
        result = num1 / num2;
        break;
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
  }
```

```html
<h3>*- - - Simple Calculator - --*</h3>
<textarea id = "no1" > </textarea>
<textarea id = "no2"> </textarea>
 <button id="add" onclick="simple_calculator(this.id)">Add</button>
 <button id="sub" onclick="simple_calculator(this.id)">Subsract</button>
 <button id="mul" onclick="simple_calculator(this.id)">Multiply</button>
 <button id="div" onclick="simple_calculator(this.id)">Divide</button>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This did the trick. However is there a way to add the id of the button instead of "this.id"?

Comment: @C.Abisheka `this.id` **is** the id of the button. Alternatively you can use: `<button id="add" onclick="simple_calculator('add')">Add</button>`  If this helped you please accept my answer.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for thanks a lot!
I have 1 more question.Is it wrong to use like this?
 num1 = document.getElementById("no1").value;
 num2 = document.getElementById("no2").value;
 num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("no2").value);
  num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("no2").value);

Comment: You have to use parseInt (or parseFloat, or Number) because the output of a `textarea` is a string not a number. If you want you can use the more verbose `num1 = document.getElementById("no1").value`. But keep in mind that the user can click the button when there is no value inside the textarea, or they may write in a string. In this case you would get `NaN` as a result. So what I'm saying is: if you get a number use that number. If you don't get a number let it be 0 (`. . . .  || 0`)